# How can I tell if my graphics card will take advantage of a 120Hz monitor?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, display, 120hz

My *specific* hardware setup is that I have a [GeForce GTX 580M](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-580m/specifications) in my laptop, and I'm considering buying an [Iiyama Prolite G2773HS monitor](http://www.novatech.co.uk/products/monitors/26inchplusmonitors/plg2773hs.html). However, I would *hope* that answers to this question would be general, rather than make/model-specific. (I can give other specs if they're useful, but I don't want to drown the question in irrelevant detail.)

I can't see anything in the manufacturer's specification to say whether or not my graphics card will really drive a 120Hz monitor (connected via Dual-Link DVI) at 120Hz, or whether I'd be completely wasting my money.

I'm running Windows 7 (and will probably upgrade to Windows 8 if that makes any difference). When I list the available modes for my graphics adapter in either the normal display settings or the NVidia control panel, it only shows 50Hz and 60Hz modes, even with the "list modes my current display doesn't support" box checked. Is this a Windows limitation which will suddenly go away via Windows Update when I plug the monitor in for the first time?

Of course one option is to try to find someone with a 120Hz monitor that I can try my *actual laptop* with first... but that's likely to be relatively tricky.

Please note: I'm not *particularly* looking for opinions on whether 120Hz monitors are a good idea or not, as there's a lot of information out there already on that topic - but answers which *happen to also contain* thoughts along those lines are welcome :)

Comment: Completely off-topic, but... too bad the "jon skeet facts" is locked. It would be fun to link this one. JS asks something, edit the only answer given, and then comments his edited answer :)

Comment: @woliveirajr To be fair, I wrote KHz instead of Hz so it was a very legitimate edit. I would have done it myself had I caught it before him.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, and was a right answer, you even got my upvoted. It was just funny...

Comment: `I can't see anything in the manufacturer's specification to say whether or not my graphics card will really drive a 120Hz monitor at 120Hz.`   Well as the page says: `Note: The below specifications represent this GPU as incorporated into NVIDIA's reference graphics card design. Graphics card specifications may vary by Add-in-card manufacturer. Please refer to the Add-in-card manufacturers' website for actual shipping specifications.`   So you’d have to check with the laptop manufacturer to find out what limits they imposed on the hardware. Also, the drivers will play a role.

Comment: (Another user asked a resolution question today and while researching it, I was baffled by the lack of specific, well specifications. In the old days, video-cards had clear, defined lists of supported graphics modes—res×bit-depth×refresh-rate—but now they barely provide any details. `¬_¬`)

Answer (score 8):

I am going to say yes but in a roundabout way.

The GeForce GTX 580M supports 3D Vision, which to perform on on LCD displays must support a [120Hz refresh rate](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/technology/3d-vision/system-requirements). So therefor I know the card can drive ***a*** 120Hz display, but I can't guarantee that it can run ***your*** 120Hz display, mainly because your display is not on the list of officially supported displays for 3D vision.

Comment: Thanks - that's a start. I guess there's a risk that Windows will support that, but not the full 120Hz for 2D... Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly as long as the screen supports exact same signal as your main board than it should work fine. All the standard screen formats are directly accessible to your pc settings and options. The only time you should run into trouble is if the connector or the cable signal is not the same on both fronts.